# How to share resource two way from the main container to a sidecar container and vice-versa

Tags: kubernetes, containers, sidecar

I have a main container and a sidecar container inside a pod. I Know  main app container and sidecar container share certain resources or data, but they are typically distinct entities with their own memory allocations. Also, sidecar might interact and share resources such as files
But I don't want to share my resources using files. Is there any other way ?

I Know  main app container and sidecar container share certain resources or data, but they are typically distinct entities with their own memory allocations. Also, sidecar might interact and share resources such as files
But I don't want to share my resources using files. Is there any other way ?

Comment: What sort of "resources" are you thinking of?  Do you have an example setup where sharing isn't working the way you expect?  Can you combine these two things into a single process/container, or separate them further into separate Deployments?

Comment: I want to share some secret from sidecar to main app and vice-versa(context: sidecar will call cloud secret using key present in main app to get secret from gcp and then sidecar will push this secret to main app.